# Would human clones suffer inferiority complex given the exact same physiology?

Tags: humans

My argument is that the mammalian brain is calibrated to seek out potential mates in an extremely competitive and hostile environment, in short I dare say everyone of us inevitably contracted the chronic I-have-no-parallel disease. My story sets in a post apocalyptic world where the machines inherited no man lands, they grew bored and decided to resurrect the modern humans via cloning(of course hybrid). These clones will be taught art and science and they eventually learn how they are brought to life. Now that these clones have a better understanding of their origin and they shares the same DNA and culture with us, would they suffer inferiority complex when compare to us? Since machine doesn't care whether the human is a clone or not, why would it matters for a human?

Comment: This feels very opinion based to me. It would all depend on how they are raised and what they are taught. They could feel superior, inferior, or the same but different...

Comment: Of course most of them would just get on with their lives most of the time. When they stopped to consider their origins, though, it would make them very sad to realize that they had once been wiped out.

Comment: Even the answers say it depends, which means this is obviously not quite fit for he site. It rests somewhere on too broad and opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there's one right answer to this question. It all depends.

Clones are a lot like identical twins. Some people who are twins are frustrated with constantly being confused for their brother/sister, feel a loss of individuality, etc. Others see their twin as someone with whom they have an especially close relationship. I'm sure there are other responses. You can't say, "This is how all twins feel about being a twin."

And that's just a step away from brothers and sisters in general. How do members of large families feel?

I wouldn't be surprised if some clones were depressed because they see themselves as just one more instance of a "product" that has been mass-produced. They could see themselves as a commodity: If something happens to me, I'll just be replaced. I have no importance as an individual.

But others would take pride in being members of this group. Just like members of a family sometimes take pride in the family, talk about "we Millers have a proud tradition" (or whatever the family name is), share credit for achievements and help each other in trouble, etc.

It would all depend on environment, social attitudes, education, and personal inclinations. (And barring the clones somehow being genetically engineered to think a certain way, I presume any attempt to "educate" them to all think alike would be futile. Any more than the average parents' efforts to bring their children up to think or believe in certain ways has only mixed success.)

Answer (score 1):

another angle to consider would be how accurate the process of recreating the human race is, and especially how accurate the clones think that it is. if the machines believe that humans were this near-perfect race of creators, than even a genetically-identical clone would be seen as a disappointment and made to feel as such. however, if the machines see us as weak, inferior pet-like beings, than they probably wont care how well the clones reflect actual humans, which would still make them feel bad about themselves but for different reasons.